# Java Deflater always returning 0 issue

Tags: java

So I have a input stream from which I read a smaller fixed-size buffer which I'm trying to Deflate inside a Runnable class.

```
randomClass implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        ...
        byte[] output = new Byte[FIXED];
        Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
        deflater.setInput(uncompressed);
        deflater.setLevel(Deflater.DEFLATED);
        int length = deflater.deflate(output);
        ...
    } 
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that length is always returning 0 which means I need more input according to the doc? However, I've checked that the uncompressed is not null. How can I get the bytes out of the output?

Also I believe I should be calling deflater.finish() only at the last block. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `compresser.finish();` should be called right after `deflater.setInput(uncompressed);`. Then proceed with the next steps, it should be fine.

Same is mentioned in the [**documentation**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html) as below:

```
 byte[] output = new byte[100];
 Deflater compresser = new Deflater();
 compresser.setInput(input);
 compresser.finish();  //<-- finished is called here
 int compressedDataLength = compresser.deflate(output);
```

Also, please set the level at the time of initialization e.g.

```
 Deflater compresser = new Deflater(Deflater.DEFLATED, false); //<-set the level
 byte[] output = new byte[100];
 compresser.setInput(input);
 compresser.finish();  //<-- finished is called here
 int compressedDataLength = compresser.deflate(output);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Should finish() still be called even if the block I'm compressing isn't the last one from the input stream?

Comment: @bph I added some more content in the answer. I think you need to add all inputs before calling `finish()` and `deflate(output)` afterwards.

Comment: The compressedDataLength still is 0 with that compression level even if I call finish.

Comment: @bph: Can you please share your `uncompressed`? I will validate and let you know.

Comment: The uncompressed is just a byte array with a fixed length. The output is only 0 when I use deflater.setLevel(Deflater.DEFLATED); The other levels seem to have a length.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The constructor did the trick... weird how there are issues if I set it after.

Comment: This does not explain why setLevel() doesn't works as expected

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `compresser.finish()` to get the final output. See the Javadoc. If you have more than one buffer it would be better to use a `DeflaterInputStream`.