# Does Deflater.setLevel() work?

Tags: java, deflate

[Deflater.setLevel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html#setLevel%28int%29) does not work as expected for me.

```
static void test1() throws Exception {
     byte[] output = new byte[20];
     Deflater compresser = new Deflater();
     // compresser.setLevel(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);
     compresser.setInput("blah".getBytes("UTF-8"));
     compresser.finish();
     int len = compresser.deflate(output);
     System.out.println("len="+ len+ " " +Arrays.toString(output));
}
```

The above works ok for me (Java 7), but when I uncomment the `compresser.setLevel()` line, it breaks (`deflate()` returns 0 bytes). The same happens with any compression level, except for `DEFAULT`. More specifically, it only "works" (rather, it's harmless) when the level set is the same that was set (explictly or implicitly, as here) in the constructor - that is to say, it only can be used when it's useless.

See an example  at [Ideone](http://ideone.com/Ek1hRw).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077306/java-deflater-always-returning-0-issue) points to the same problem, and the accepted answer basically says: do't set the level with the setter, do it in the constructor. Far from satisfactory, IMO - why does `setLevel()` exists? Is it broken or are we missing something?

Comment: It appears to be a bug in the `Deflater` API... Reading the javadoc, it is not clear at all what `.finish()` really does. Does the workaround proposed in the last answer work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dug a little into the JDK source code.  It does indeed set the level.  If you follow the `setLevel()` with `compresser.deflate(new byte[0]);`, then it will work.

What's happening is that the first call of `deflate()` after the `setLevel()` will see that the level is changed, and call zlib's `deflateParams()` function to change it.  `deflateParams()` will then compress the available data, but the fact that you asked for a `finish()` is not passed along.  The JDK implementation then does not call `deflate()` with `Z_FINISH`.  As a result, the data you gave is sent for compression, the compressor accumulates the data, but it does not emit a compressed block since it was not asked to finish.  So you get nothing.

You need the call to `deflate()` after the `setLevel()` to actually set the level. Then subsequent data will be compressed with the new level.

It is important to note that data provided up to the first `deflate()` call after the `setLevel()` will be compressed with the *old* compression level.  Only data provided after that `deflate()` call will use the new level.  So if in your example you simply did another `deflate()` after the last one, it would apply the `finish()` and you would get your compressed data, but it would use the default compression level.

Comment: "the fact that you asked for a finish() is not passed along" That would be a bug, isn't it?

Comment: I would say yes.  Especially since I don't see where that behavior is documented.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is a bug.

If you look into the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/zip/Deflater.java), you will find that only in the constructor do they call the native method `init` which **actually** sets the level of compression. It seems that the compression level must be set before any of the native `init` calls take place .ie Before the creation of the `Deflater` object.

The `setLevel(int)` just sets the level for the object superficially. There is no call to the native library.

Comment: It would have been bad enough that `setLevel()` were a NOP in disguise (fixed in... [1998](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4152809)) , but it's worse, it seems to break the decompression.

Comment: The next call of `deflate()` sets the level.